# Routing to a specific user profile using iron router (METEOR)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

As the question says, I need to create a specific route for every user that I have. In my case employers. Now all the examples on the web are connected with the USERS collection.

In my case I want to route to: `"/employer/:_id"` but I have the `Employer ID` in the `Collection Employers`. So basically I have to get the `Employer ID` via the key from `User ID`

Im kinda stuck on returning the Employer ID value to the route...

METHODS.js

```
getEmployerId: function(currentuser){
    employerId = Employer.find({"user":currentuser}).fetch();
    return employerId;
}
```

ROUTER.js

```
  Router.route("/employer/:_id", {
  name:"employer",
  template:"employer",
  layoutTemplate:'employerLayout',
    data: function(){
      var currentuser = Meteor.userId();
      Meteor.call("getEmployerId", currentuser, function(error, result){
        if(error){
          console.log("error", error);
        }
        if(result){
           return true;  // I belive here is where I have to pass it up to the ROUTE
        }
      });

    },
    onBeforeAction:function(){

      var user = Meteor.userId();
        if(!user || !Roles.userIsInRole(user, ['employer'])) {
          Router.go("verification");
        }else {
          this.next();
        }
        return true;

    },

});
```

And this is how my Employer collection looks like:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.employer.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : "qCFGZa4ogc5LR56PL", // I need this for the route
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-18T13:19:16.098Z"),
    "user" : "owfJ4ozrfsp26o8G4" // the key through which i can return the ID, got it from the user session?
}
```

Anyone has a suggestion how to do this? And is this a good approach for each user(employer) profile? Any tutorial, example or anything that describes an application with user profiles would be much appriciated!

Comment: Do you really need the employee ID? You can find the employee using the user id

Comment: Yes I want the employer ID as there will be much more info later regarding the employer. It makes more sense to me. And yes I do find the ID but don't know how to pass it back to the route?

Comment: Ok, I guess you have a template with a list of employers, and you want to click on an employer to get more info, or similar?

Comment: Actually, When a specific user (employer) logs in he is automatically redirected to his profile page. Lets say: /employer/1111111 . Now on that page he will have all his options (jobs postings, preferences and so on).

So I basically check on the route which employer it is (based on the user id) and give him his proflie , fairly simillar like facebook or any other profile based app

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like you're nearly there.

I don't think you want the ::id parameter. You send the user to simply `/employer`, where he does the sign in, so you have his user id.

Then change `getEmployerId` to `getEmployer`: in other words, get the whole of the employer record.

```
getEmployer: function(currentuser){
    return Employer.find({"user":currentuser}).fetch();
}
```

Then in your `data:` function of the router instead of returning `true` you return the record you find. In this way the record is available for your template (that's what the `data` function is for)

```
data: function(){
  var currentuser = Meteor.userId();
  Meteor.call("getEmployer", currentuser, function(error, result){
    if(error){
      console.log("error", error);
    }
    if(result){
       return result;
    }
  });

},
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info on retrieving! But how can I have his "link" so to say. I get the data, thats fine and now would just like to pass his "Employer ID" as the full profile link: etc. localhost:300/employer/1000000

Comment: Well, my point is that I don't think you need to redirect him anywhere. But then maybe I haven't quite understood you. As I see it the user calls the /employer route (the ::id parameter is not needed), and this /employer route displays an 'employer' template showing the employer record. The router supplies the employer record to the template in the 'data:' function. No need to redirect the user anywhere, no need to supply the employer id to the route.

Comment: But in the later stages when I will have a "public proflie" section, I would like to be able to reference to a specific user via his "employer link like mentioned above". It's just something that I think I might use throughout the whole app (as I will have the employee section too) so would like to know how to implement it somehow. Sorry for bothering! :)

Comment: You certainly aren't bothering me. As I say, since you have the user, you just call /employer. Whenever he calls that route, if he is signed in, you have the userId, if he isn't, he has to sign in, so you always have the userId when your 'data' function is called. So you don't need the employerID here. It's just a complication. If you really want to get the employerID, you will have to go twice to the database: once to get the employerID, then again to get the employer record. However the 'pathFor' function in the template is very useful and is designed to supply hrefs for links.

Comment: Okay, would you have a specific example based on my code as I don't really know how to implement it? :(